Windows 10 Installation - 0x8019001
I have a desktop with Windows 10 and can't login to any Microsoft account.
Initially, this was my computer and I bypassed this issue by simply not logging in and blocking this PC from 365 (I'm the admin).
I now want to repurpose this for my daughter. I performed a clean reinstall and created a Microsoft account for her. I immediately got 0x8019001 error when trying to login to Edge. Tried a variety of actions - repair Microsoft store, change password, etc.
Eventually I rebooted and that's when the PC got bricked. It still wouldn't login, except now to the OS. I get the message "Retry or Cancel to complete setup later".
Every couple of boots it would display "You need an app for this" when I clicked the login button. When I click reboot, I get "Someone is still using this PC".
I have a Linux partition or disk that is not booted. It's possible the boot process gets routed through grub, though not likely.
I was not asked to input my key. It's a legal Windows 10 (New Computer) that was already registered to this motherboard.
Questions:

Am I missing something. I used to think the issue was with my work Microsoft account. But now it seems an issue with the computer or my network?
I have access to a usb drive with Linux. Can I somehow revert this installation to local login? I assume I can reset the password from Linux. I can live without an MS account for my daughter.

Update
I logged into cmd prompt.
net users shows the expected admin, default, guest and utility accounts. It also says 'The command completed with one or more errors.'
I added an account using net user <user> <pass> /add and got 'user successfully created but could not be added to the USERS local group'.
net users shows the new account. dir c:\users doesn't show a folder for it. Reboot to cmd doesn't show it again.
wmic os get Caption returns a very vague 'Microsoft'
2nd Update
Reinstalled from scratch. Used oobe/bypassNRO to use local login. Still can't login to Microsoft account.

"I was not asked to input my key." - This is perfectly normal.  Windows 10 is activated digitally. Windows 8+ automatically detect the license key associated with the system if it's an OEM license and a digital entitlement is done with a retail license. "wmic os get Caption" - is only valid for OEM Windows images, once you reinstall the Windows, you no longer were using an OEM Windows image.

Do you have your kid's account set up in Microsoft Family as a child? I had my family entirely set up in Microsoft Family, and then logging in on the computers using the kid's accounts was super simple, no special config, it just worked.

This is the problem with mixing cloud with on-prem code. It works fine if you start where you did. If you install Windows 10 and do this, it should spawn a page to link the new child account to a parent one. It didn't and so the process broke Anyway, it works now.

Spent a while before looking at the page URL that shows the error in non-login attempts. I think it was MS Edge login attempt.
It seems MS did not button down support for children accounts. There's a redirect at some point to a page that doesn't display anything or shows an error.
Once I figured that, I looked for more info online and reviews of this were less than favorable.
Armed with the knowledge, I reinstalled and created an adult account for my child (not great) and it works.
